# How to exclude a specific category from blog posts

Tags: php, wordpress

How to exclude a specific category from blog posts in WordPress but if a blog post has two categories selected, one from excluded category and the other from included I would like to show the blog post.

```
function exclude_category_home( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-7' );
    }
    return $query;
}
 
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_home' );
```

I tried using this function in function.php, it hides the excluded category but when two categories are selected for one blog post, it still hides

Comment: Do you know the list of categories that need to show?

Comment: No, since there will be more categories added in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* you may try this code and use category__not_in function */

   function exclude_posts_from_home_page( $query )
   {
       if( $query->is_home() )
       {
           $query->set( 'category__not_in', array( 7 ) ); // here array of all category ids
      }
   }
   add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_posts_from_home_page' );
```